# Make Tab Active Programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a certain tab made active programmatically when the div is made visible using the following:

```
$("#myTab").tabs("option", "active", 0); // Focus on Employee Tab
```

When using this I receive the following console.log message:

**Error: cannot call methods on tabs prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'option'**

This code has been placed in the document ready script.  Thanks for any help.  :)

Comment: post the whole script. Or a fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p3sfy/4250/)

Use this method,

```
$("#myTab").tabs({active : <tab number>});
```

or

```
$("#myTab").tabs({active : 0});
```

---

**[Demo With your code](http://jsfiddle.net/p3sfy/4251/)**.

In your case you need to initialize the tabs first. If you don't you get an error, as you are directly calling a function on tabs.

```
$("#myTab").tabs();  //initialize  
$("#myTab").tabs("option", "active", 0);  //set tab
```

or

```
$("#myTab").tabs().tabs("option", "active", 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to manually trigger a click event on a specific tab:-

```
  var tabname = "employee";
  tabEL = $('#myTav [data-tab-name="'+ tabName +'"]');
  tabEL.click();
```

Comment: There is no need to do some trickery. jQuery UI Api has such method http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active

Answer (score 1):

For some reason this code is executed before the tab are initialize. Assumimg you're using jQuery UI tabs. Check if you got `$("myTab").tabs();` before the activation code.